# AnyLogic: Calculating the sum of all values in a collection

Tags: java, collections, simulation, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I have an agent-based simulation where I have a collection called `collection_dailyInfection` which has the numbers of new infections that arise on a daily basis. The collection looks a bit like this:

- Day 1: 0
- Day 2: 3
- Day 4: 3
- Day 5: 6
- Day 6: 1
- .  .  .

I'm now trying to write a function that adds up the total number of infections on any particular day. For example: on Day 6- total infections = 0+3+3+6+1 = 13.

The syntax for calculating the sum is:
`double sum( collection, value )` - *Returns the sum of values in the given collection.*

For my particular example, this would be `double sum( collection_dailyInfection, *value*)`, but I'm not sure what I should put in the 'value' argument. Could some help me out please?

Comment: Which other calls are ok? Maybe `double sum( collection, key )` (meaning the keys should be summarized)? If so, it makes sense.

Comment: Could you show a (part) working program, it might help identify a proper solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These functions (methods) provided by AnyLogic for calculating statistics on collections use a fairly advanced feature of Java: the functional programming stuff added in Java 8. So the required syntax is not at all obvious. The main help page (**AnyLogic Help --> Parameters, Variables, Collections --> Collections --> Functions to collect statistics on a collection**) has a link to the `UtilitiesCollection` class where these methods are defined.

You have a collection `collection_dailyInfection` of daily infection counts; let's assume you specified this in AnyLogic as being of collection class  `ArrayList` with elements class as `int`, and you used a cyclic event to add the count each simulated day.

Your sum expression should therefore be

`sum( collection_dailyInfection, c -> c.doubleValue())`

The `c` is just an arbitrary identifier for the current element that the sum is on (effectively this sum method is looping through your collection) and the `->` is a special Java 8 functional programming operator. When you specify type `int` in AnyLogic for your collection contents, they are actually stored as `Integer` objects which are object versions of the `int` primitives. (See any Java textbook to understand this.)

Thus, each entry (`Integer` object) has a method `doubleValue` which returns the value of the integer as a double. (AnyLogic's `sum` function needs the 'value' bit to be a `double`; i.e., a real (floating point) number.)

(anupam691997's answer is a 'pure Java' solution ignoring the AnyLogic context.)

Answer (score 0):

**Value** should be an integer, It will denote that day till which you want the total number of infections.

For example in this case the value of **value** should be 6. Since you want to the total number of infections till 6th day.

Here is a working demo of what you wanted

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> list;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        list=new ArrayList<Integer>();  /* this list will hold all the values*/
        int total=sc.nextInt(); /* total number of values in the list */
        int value=sc.nextInt(); /* the day till which you want the total infection */

        for(int i=0;i<total;i++)  /*taking input in the list */
            list.add(sc.nextInt());

        double sum=calculateSum(list,value); /* function to compute sum*/

        System.out.println(sum);
    }

    static double calculateSum(ArrayList<Integer> list,int value)
    {
        double sum=0.0;
        for(int j=0;j<value;j++) /* calculates sum from day 1 till value*/
            sum=sum+list.get(j);
        return sum; 
    }


}
```